# Adding a class to a specific item that is true to an if statement but has the same class as other elements

Tags: jquery, if-statement, addclass

I am making a scholarship website for my school and I am wanting to add a class to the scholarships if the scholarship due date has passed. Each scholarship has the class .month.

### **HTML**

```
<li class="month 11 start" data-due-date="11/11/2014 1:00">
    <time class="cbp_tmtime"><span>Nov. 11, 2014</span></time>
    <div class="cbp_tmicon"></div>
    <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
        <h2>November</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Website</a> | <a href="#">PDF</a>
    </div>
</li>

<li class="month 12 start" data-due-date="12/11/2014 1:00">
    <time class="cbp_tmtime"><span>Dec. 11, 2014</span></time>
    <div class="cbp_tmicon"></div>
    <div class="cbp_tmlabel">
        <h2>December</h2>
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Website</a> | <a href="#">PDF</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

### **Jquery**

```
function getData(){
     var scholarship = $('.month');
     var data = $(scholarship).data("due-date");
     var dataDate = new Date(data);
     var today = new Date();


     if(dataDate < today){

     }

}
```

I have looked for days for ways to do this but i couldn't figure it out. This is as far as i got. Please help :/ this has been irritating me like crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the testing for each `.month` element

```
function getData(){
     var scholarships = $('.month'),
         today = new Date();

     scholarships.each(function(){
         var scholarship = $(this),
             data = scholarship.data("due-date"),
             dataDate = new Date(data);

         if(dataDate < today){
             scholarship.addClass('expired');
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!! Thank you!!! I was trying to use each but i guess i didn't use it correctly lol. I appreciate it! :)